# OVS - Open vSwitch

Tags: wireless, network-bridge

I installed OVS and added WLAN0 interface in vSwitch. Its work fine but after reboot PC, linux cannot find WLAN0 interface and cannot connect to access point.

Ifconfig cannot show WLAN0. I think that need something add to /etc/network/interfaces but I tried and I failed.

Sorry, I am not linux specialist but I know linux fundamentals :P

PS. If I added eth0 in vSwitch(without WLAN0 interface) situation is same :D

Answer (score 0):

Persistent names of the interfaces can be created via udev. Please find below example of persistent Ethernet (eth0) and WiFi (wlan0-3) names based on the MAC addresses of the interfaces.

```
# cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="f0:de:f1:bb:18:7b", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# 03:00.0 Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085]
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="10:0b:a9:3b:5c:6c", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
# No name; 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:13:ef:c2:01:86", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan1"
# TP-Link TL-WDN3200; 148f:5572 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5572 Wireless Adapter
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="64:70:02:27:d6:42", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan2"
# No name; 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:13:ef:c2:04:7e", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan3
```